# Joining two tables Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, join

I would like to have some feedback on how to join two tables using Laravel. I have read the documentation but still I am a little bit confused. And I'm still thinking on how to handle the problem. See... I have two tables one for the kids information and the other for the vaccines, I decided to put it apart because there are a lot of vaccines and I don't want the user to input every vaccine each time they add a new kid to the system. I am planning on making some type of checkboxes for the administrator to select the vaccines each kid has, but then I have the date, so I don't know what will be the best approach.
And one of my questions is, how will I retrieve the data from the vaccines table when the user is filling out the kids information? Or do you guys have a better sugestion? I already have the table of the kids up and running, but now I have to add the vaccines.
I would glady appreaciate your help. I will also leave a picture of the two tables.

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have `idkid` as the primary key and `id` as a foreign key? Also, do you know how you would query this using a plain sql query? If so, would you be able to show what the raw query would be.

Comment: oh yeah I'm sorry for not explaining about that. id is the id from the users table, idguardian is from the guardians table, which are foreign keys with the kids table which has an unique idkid

Comment: and about the query I am still kind of confused on how to join the tables with a query, because I still don't know how to handle the second table (vaccines)I don't know if I should get rid of the date and just handle the type of the vaccine on the extra table, or what can I do

Comment: I would personally say you want to use a `many-to-many` relationship so you would need to add a intermediate table.

Comment: that's what I was thinking about, because I think that the date and the description field of the vaccines table are redundant, because the main purpose of that particular table is to store all the names of the vaccines (since I don't want the user to input them each time they add a kid) so at the end I mainly just want to retrieve the data from that table, and let the user select which vaccines does the kid have. But I still want to have a type of date when the vaccine was received on the kid, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding you will need to keep another table that would manage the interaction between `kids` and `vaccines` lets say `kids_vaccines`.

This means that, every kid that receive one or many vaccines would have their record added with timestamp of the time the vaccine(s) was received

An example would be:

Having `KidsVaccine` model with relationship with `Kid` and `Vaccine` like

```
public function kid()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Kid::class, 'idkid');
}

public function vaccine()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Vaccine::class, 'idvaccine');
}
```

And both your `Kid` model and `Vaccine` model can bear a `hasMany()` relationship with `KidsVaccine`

This means that, in lets say `kids_vaccines` table you would be managing `idkid` and `idvacccine` as both foreign keys (ofcourse your timestamps are here, so as to know when a vaccine was applied to a kid).

This results that you can easily create a kids with vaccines retrievable from the `vaccines` table.

If there is anything unclear you can point it.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing the many-to-many relationship and the pivot table :)